# Open-CV 2.4 Dense SIFT with contrast threshold

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm trying to compute dense SIFT with openCV-python 2.4

```
import cv2
def gen_sift_features(gray, step_size, gamma):
    dense = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense")
    dense.setInt('initXyStep',step_size)
    kp = dense.detect(gray)

    sift = cv2.SIFT(contrastThreshold=gamma)
    kp, desc = sift.compute(gray, kp)
    return kp, desc

img = cv2.imread('myimage.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kp, desc = gen_sift_features(gray, 8, 0.01)
```

Normally, the contrast threshold will filter out the keypoints at low-contrast regions but in this case, it was ignored and openCV still give me sifts descriptors for all the keypoints.

[image]

Anyone knows how to filter out the low-contrast descriptors in this case?
Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I tried to look closer and removed all the null descriptors

```
remove = []
for i in range(0,len(desc)):
   if sum(desc[i])==0:
       remove.append(i)

np.delete(desc,remove)
for i in sorted(remove, reverse=True):
    del kp[i]
```

[image]

But when I changed my contrastThreshold, the result is still the same!!!!
Seem like the parameter is still **ignored**

Comment: Which values did you use for the threshold? From the c++ [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html), the default threshold is 0.04 and note that 'the larger the threshold, the less features are produced by the detector.'

Comment: I want to use 0.01 but I tested all range of values from 0 to 1. Normally if I use 1 with normal SIFT, it'll produce and error since none of the descriptors is kept. But in dense SIFT, this value is ignored

Comment: So, you want to use **dense keypoints** and **sift descriptors**. If you use **sift keypoints** and **sift descriptors** the threshold is not ignored right? I can only conclude that the contrast threshold is only used when extracting the **keypoints**.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think too. Finally I have to install the trial version of Matlab to use VLFeat

Comment: I never tried myself, but if VLFeat is a requirement for your project I think you can use the Matlab scripts in Octave (which is free). Heres the [tutorial](http://www.vlfeat.org/install-octave.html) on how to compile VLFeat to use it in Octave.

Answer (score 1):

With your example in mind, I would simply use an Laplacian filter [0] to find high-frequency regions (see also the edge detection tutorial of opencv [1]). You can then turn its response in a mask by thresholding it and retrieve active pixels of the mask using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def find_high_contrast_key_points(img, threshold):
    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
    high_contrast_r, high_contrast_c = np.where(laplacian > threshold)

    kp = [cv2.KeyPoint(x, y, 1) for y, x in zip(high_contrast_r, high_contrast_c)]

    return kp
```

The `cv2.Laplacian` filter in OpenCV takes a size argument, which you might want to use. Additional modifications of the Laplacian output could also be done with morphological operations [2].

[0]  http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=laplacian#cv2.Laplacian

[1] http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html

[2] http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html?highlight=morphology